# Using R coded functions in python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, rpy2

I am a beginner in python and need help with using R coded files in python. I have a file that is coded in R and contains functions that I would like to use in my google collab python file. Currently, I have the file in my google drive.  When I open it, it get opened using the notepad. I would like to know how I can use the functions from the R file in the python script. I have tried using the rpy2 module, and the `rpy2.robjects.r` method along with the file path. But it just throws an error

```
 Error in source("/content/drive/My Drive/Python files/python files/R functions.R") : 
  invalid multibyte character in parser at line 119
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> source
```

if anyone knows what to do please do tell me

this is the code i tried to implement:

```
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

robjects.r('''source('/content/drive/My Drive/Python files/python files/R functions.R')''')   

r_getrpm = robjects.globalenv['Tachometer.speed']

def rpm(rinput):
    return(r_getrpm(Data_input = rinput, Min_trigger = 3, Max_trigger = 4, Range_accept = 2, Min_accept = 4,
                                 Tachometer_pulse = 6, Sampling_rate = 100000, Checks = False, Show_plot = False, Reforming = False,
                                 R_From = 1, R_To = 50000, R_Multi = 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the coding problem. When you use rpy2, the windows system is using another coding format, I have the same issue, and looking into the rpy2 document, to look if they have an coding option.